# Fastboot not dectecting device mac

Tags: fastboot, macos

I'm trying to flash TWRP on my Samsung but during the flashing process, fastboot can't detect my device. I've looked around forever and can't find anything to help me.

My mac OS is Ventura and my phone i'm using is the: Samsung Galaxy S10+ (SM-G975F)

Comment: Had terrible luck with this too years ago. Have you tried using a VM, or running Linux/Windows directly which would likely be more successful?